# Is there a way to see the UI of an angular application in design time without running the application?

Tags: angular, user-interface, localization

I work on localisation engineering for an application that is developed in Angular. Since, the application is heavy and needs to enter lot of data in various pages to navigate to a particular screen, I am trying to do a quick check of the screens at design time to verify if the screens have been localized. Is there a way to check the look and feel of UI without running the application?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is rendering the page based on the values set in ts code. You can set data manually in component.html and run the file in browser.